# problem with "using namespace arma" in building arbitrary RcppArmadillo package

Tags: armadillo, roxygen

I'm trying to compile an arbitrary package that is mainly written in RcppArmadillo. Below is an example of my source code:

```
// [[Rcpp::interface(r,cpp)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

//' test function
//'
//' @param kap, a scalar value
//' @param m, an integer
//' @return a scalar value
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double test_function(double kap, uword m){
       return kap * m;
}
```

I use the following command to create a package skeleton:

```
RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton(name = "test")
```

Then I add the source code file and compile attributes:

```
compileAttributes("test")
```

This creates the RcppExport.cpp file, for some reason, even though I used the line "using namespace arma" in my original source file, it is not transfered into the RcppExport.cpp file, nor is it in the header file created in connection to Rcpp::interface. So I add this line to the RcppExport.cpp and RcppExport.h file myself. Then I try to do roxygenise:

```
roxygen::roxygenise("test")
```

and I get an error message:

```
'uword' has not been declared
```

I'm confused because I had clearly put "using namespace arma;" in all the necessary files, but roxygen doesn't seem to be understanding that.... Is there some other file where I should have declared namespace arma? Or do I have to use arma::uword in my source file?

Comment: I have thousands of lines of code, it would be really annoying if I have to go back and add "arma::" to everything. I would really appreciate a quicker solution, thank you~~